# I was curious if there was any performance loss using includes

Tags: php, html, include

I was curious if there would be any performance loss using PHP includes as opposed to just having the html(for example, navigation) written on the page, and if so is it significant? I do understand the benefits, I was just curious if there were negatives.

Comment: `include()` should be extremely fast. Even if there were any performance differences, it would be microscopically small.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there are file access on `includes` so there are resources consumption.

But as soon as the code is op_cached it's nothing (check [APC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators)).